# How to know when a .net WebMethod has returned its value?

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to c# Webservices. I have a WebMethod that will return a large amount of data. Therefore it should be possible to view the status of a transfer. How can i know if and when a WebMethod has returned its value? Can i bind to an event or something?

The method in question looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<TEST.Models.ArticleModel> GetArticles(string terminalSerial)
{
    Communication comm = new Communication {
        StartDate = DateTime.Now,
        Status = "Started"
    };
    var terminal = (from t in context.Terminals
                    where t.SerialNumber == terminalSerial
                    select t).FirstOrDefault();
    var articles = from a in context.Articles
                   where a.CountryID == terminal.Customer.CountryID
                      && a.LastEdit > terminal.LastSync
                   select new TEST.Models.ArticleModel {
                       ArticleID = a.ArticleID,
                       ArticleGroupID = a.ArticleGroupID,
                       ArticleGroupName = a.ArticleGroup.Name,
                       CountryName = a.Country.Name,
                       Description = a.Description,
                       EAN = a.EAN,
                       SAPID = a.SAPID
                   };
    terminal.LastSync = DateTime.Now;
    comm.TerminalID = terminal.TerminalID;
    context.SubmitChanges();
    return articles.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Surely you mean from the calling context, so how are you calling it?

Comment: It does not appear that WebMethod will make your function async.  Which means you will have to do exactly that.  You can use a callback and events to report the progress.

Comment: That sounds right. I have decided to follow the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719796(v=vs.71).aspx, but i seem to be missing a reference to an assembly. I cannot resolve the RemoteService and AuthorRoyalties classes. I tried google'ing it though...

Comment: So, i took the easy way, and added a GetArticlesComplete Webmethod, for the client to call. Far from the optimal solution i was looking for. I didn't want to leave anything to the client. But i guess this is agains the nature of webservices. Being stateless and all. At least i couldn't find a way of handling all logic on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Server Side :** 
use logging or write the list to nrmal file like this :

```
[WebMethod]
public List<TEST.Models.ArticleModel> GetArticles(string terminalSerial)
{

//..... your code here

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
List<TEST.Models.ArticleModel> theList = articles.ToList();
file.WriteLine("you have "+ theList.Count );
for(ArticleModel articleModel : theList)
   file.WriteLine(articleModel.ToString());

file.Close();
}
```

Same thing in Client Side , call the WebService and Write the Result to File .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to know, on the client side, how to notify the user that the transfer has been completed.

Generally, Ajax requests have a way to hook up into at least 2 events from the client side: the "OnSucess" and "OnError." One of them will be called depending on whether the request finished successfully or not. For example consider this code (using JQuery to perform the request):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "YourMebService.asmx/GetArticles",
   data: "{'terminalSerial': '" + "your_value_here" + "'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(msg) {
     alert('Your request completed successfully');
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert('There was a problem processing the request');
   }
});
```

The code above basically is doing the following:

Issues an HTTP-POST request to a Webservice called `YourwebService.asmx` which exposes a method called `GetArticles` (look at the url parameter)

The `data` parameter is setting the parameters the WebMethod expects, in this case, is just a parameter called `terminalSerial` of type string.
   If the request completes successfully, the `success` function will be called; if it doesn't, the `error` function will be called.

Comment: I might not have been clear enough about what i wanted. I want everything to be handled by the server. If a client, for some reason, does not receive the data returned by the server, the server should know. I don't care about the client, but for logging purposes, the server should know if a transfer went wrong.

Comment: @Andreas you can't do it with this approach. HTTP is a disconnected protocol. Perhaps you should approach it differently, using websockets to send/receive data and detect errors on the server side. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket